# cloudflare's mx record should set cname or A records

Tags: cloudflare, mx

The cloudflare offical support said

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168876-My-email-or-mail-stopped-working-What-should-I-do-

But traditionally mx record should not set as cname

http://www.exchangepedia.com/blog/2006/12/should-mx-record-point-to-cname-records.html

But cloudflare has a service called  "cname Flattening" is it related for a reason to set cname as mx records?

So should i set cloudflare's mx record as cname ?

Comment: I do not know cloudflare or what their *flattening* is. CNAME is an alias of sorts that point to another record that can be resolved. I have always used a sub-domain name with an A record for my MX records, but I cannot imagine that a CNAME would not work if it is pointed to the domain name. You can always try it and see. No harm or fowl. Just test it during quiet time.

Comment: When you set an `MX` record in CloudFlare, you enter the _hostname_ for your mail server (e.g., `mail.example.com`) with a _priority_ value. That hostname can either be a `CNAME` also added to your DNS Settings, or an `A` record - the choice is yours and depends on your server setup (e.g., if you use an external mail server or not).

Answer (score 1):

You have to find out what your MX record was before you migrated to Cloudflare.

If the MX record was pointing to your main domain, for example domain.com, AND if you are passing your main domain through Cloudflare (arrow through the cloud in your DNS Zone Editor), then you have to do what Cloudflare tells you to do.

If the MX record was pointing to your mailserver directly, then you can add that record directly in Cloudflare.

If you are unsure about MX record, ask your e-mail/hosting provider what is the correct MX record for e-mails for your domain.